# Java – Unable to rename project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm still unable to rename my Java application in Eclipse despite the many things that I tried. I've listed what I have tried so far and attached an image of what exactly my issue is.

Basically, I'm trying to change the name of my application when it runs. I want its new name to be Cylinder rather than its old name, which was Counter.

On the Java program title, it says Cylinder, but not the Mac bar, which still says Counter.

[image]

What I tried:
1. I tried right-clicking my existing project, clicked on Refactor, and then Rename, but that didn't change much. It still appears as "Counter" on the Mac bar.
2. I tried creating another project in Eclipse called "Cylinder" and putting all of my project files into there, but it still retained "Counter" on the Mac bar.

Comment: Are you using a build tool, like ant or mavern?

Comment: It's possible this is a bug.  Have you tried quitting and restarting Eclipse?

Comment: @SamRedway No, I'm not

Comment: @dimo414 Yes, multiple times over the span of many weeks

Comment: Open the .project file and try to rename the project name there

Comment: Yeah, that would be the next thing I'd try, create a new project but only copy over your source files, not all the contents (namely `.project` and `.settings/`).

Comment: Do you have `System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");` and `System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "App Name");` set somewhere?